# Mobx react form doesn't update the type property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-form

I have the following component:

```
@observer class ElectroTextField extends React.Component {
    @observable localState = {
        showPassword: false
    }

    handleClickShowPassword = () => {
        const { field } = this.props
        this.localState.showPassword = !this.localState.showPassword
        console.log('field: ', field)
        if( field.type == 'password' ){
            field.set('type', 'text')
        }
        else {
            //this.props.field.set(this.props.field.type, 'password')
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { field } = this.props
        return (
            <TextField
                {...field.bind()}
                error={field.hasError}
                helperText={field.showError ? field.error : ''}
                required={field.rules === 'required'}
                margin="normal"
                InputProps={ field.type === 'password' ? {
                    endAdornment:
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                            <IconButton
                                aria-label="Toggle password visibility"
                                onClick={this.handleClickShowPassword}
                            >
                                {
                                    this.localState.showPassword  
                                        ? 
                                        <Visibility /> 
                                        : 
                                        <VisibilityOff />
                                }
                            </IconButton>
                        </InputAdornment>
                } : null}
            />
        );
    }
}


export default ElectroTextField;
```

and:

```
...
<FormSection form={form} section="changePassword">
  <ElectroTextField field={form.$('changePassword.password')} />
  <ElectroTextField field={form.$('changePassword.confirmPassword')} />
</FormSection>
...
```

which comes from:

```
...
    {
        name: 'changePassword',
        label: 'Change your password',
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'password',
                label: t('user:New pasword'),
                validators: [isNotEmpty, shouldBeAtleast8('changePassword.password')],
                value: itemData.passowrd,
                type: 'password',
                related: ['changePassword.confirmPassword']
            },
            {
                name: 'confirmPassword',
                label: t('user:Confirm password'),
                validators: [isNotEmpty, shouldBeEqualTo('changePassword.password')],
                value: itemData.confirmPassowrd,
                type: 'password'
            }
        ]
    },
...
```

The value of the type from the console.log gets changed to text, however the actual input type doesn't get updated at all.

Comment: Is the `field` prop an observable value?

Comment: You cannot change `props`, they are immutable. Put the `field` attribute into state. Just make the default state the prop value if you need to be able to set the default value from the parent.

Comment: @Tholle it's not, it's a prop passed down. See updated.

Comment: @pmac89 I am not, this "field.set('type', 'text')" should be responsible to make that update happen

Comment: @Alex is `field` a function or a value? Because to me it looks like a value.

Comment: @pmac89 it's an object that has properties and methods: https://foxhound87.github.io/mobx-react-form/docs/api-reference/fields-methods.html

Comment: @Alex my guess is something is not triggering the re-render. My guess is because it isn't actually changing the properties value in the parent.

Comment: @pmac89 the mobx react form has a method called "set" where you pass the property you want to change as a string and the value as a second parameter. That does updated the field property but not the actual type of the input in the DOM. What worked after many trial and erros was to update like so "filed.tpye = text" which looks a bit dirty

Comment: Yeah, that's not what the documentation say. Weird.